# Why index.js is necessary even if I change my main entry point to app.js in package.json?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, package.json, entry-point

In my react application I've changed my main entry point from index.js to app.js. But somehow, if I don't import the app.js to my index.js, the program crashes. Is there anyone who know the reason?

Comment: What does your project look like? Are you using Create React App (react-scripts) or do you have a webpack config to share?

Comment: ans to this qtn depends on how you created the app and how did you change the entry point

Answer (score 0):

in the `index.js` it searchs for an `html` element with a specific `id` most probably `app` and put it inside the `main` tag, and in the other hand if you notice that the root component `div` `id` is the same `id` that the `index.js` tries to search for

Comment: yes it looks for html element its id named as root in my project. But why index.js makes this even I've changed my entry point. Is it always responsibility of index.js ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **Create React App** template then entry for your app is defined as `src/index` in webpack config by default. check here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-dev-utils#webpackhotdevclient

Or if you are building your app from scratch then you can set your entry anything else in the webpack config file.

> what if you want to change entry point in a **create react app** ?

at first **Eject** from **CRA** . then create your own configuration including webpack